# Painfully Obvious Moderators - Know when a post is theirs

Tags: script

### Screenshots

[image]

[image]

### About

February 11, 2014. [Complaints are raised on Meta Stack Overflow over the invisibility of moderator diamonds.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/220442/223030) One helpful answerer humorously suggested

> [image: red dashed borders and a flashing "Moderator" sign]

This is (roughly) what this script does.

#### License

[**The MIT License**](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)

#### Download

[**Userscript**](https://gist.github.com/michaelb958/8949638/raw/0a7e23a7047951c3f68fa5ef530a912b5d9edb9f/modrater.user.js)

#### Platform

Runs on any browser that jQuery supports (which is quite a few). Requires some CSS3 features to work at 100%.

### Contact

It's just me, [@michaelb958](https://stackexchange.com/users/1048581/michaelb958?tab=accounts). You can contact me by:

- Commenting on or answering this post. This is the preferred mechanism for providing feedback or suggestions.
- Pinging me on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). For general conversation and stuff.
- Emailing me (email address available on [my GitHub profile](https://github.com/michaelb958)). For use in case of emergency.

### Code

jQuery, with a dash of JavaScript.
[Github Gist!](https://gist.github.com/michaelb958/8949638)

Comment: About time. I don't see how any Stack Exchange site could survive this long without such feature.

Comment: doesn't work for me in chrome

Comment: @user689 I've had several reports of breakage so far. (Should have expected them, given that initial development was done on IE.) Investigation in progress.

Comment: @michaelb958 - The problem is in your userscript's include. I replaced with `@include http://*.stackoverflow.com/*` just as a test, and it worked in Chrome. Hope this helps.

Comment: Darn. Regex `include`s were so cool... *updates ALL the scripts*